# PHP - Yii2 MPDF not rendering tables

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf

I am using mpdf extension in Yii2 for generating pdf (http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-mpdf/)

The code is given below.

```
$fileName = 'tst.pdf';
    $invoiceHtml = "
    <table style = 'height:500px;width:500px' border='1'>
      <tr>
        <td>Test
        </td>
        <td>Test2
        </td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test
          </td>
          <td>Test2
          </td>
        </tr>
    <table>
    ";
    $pdf = new Pdf([
         // set to use core fonts only
         'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
         // A4 paper format
         'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_LANDSCAPE,
         // stream to browser inline
         'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
         // your html content input
         'content' => $invoiceHtml,
         'filename' =>$fileName,
         'cssInline' => ' @page{size: 500mm 200mm}',

          // set mPDF properties on the fly
         'options' => ['title' => 'Krajee Report Title'],
          // call mPDF methods on the fly
         'methods' => [
             'SetHeader'=>['New Horizon Travel And Tours LLC'],
         ]
   ]);
   return $pdf->render();
```

The code is generating blank pdf file. I have tried other HTML tags and other tags and plain text is working as expected. When table tag is used it is working.
Looking for a solution for this problem

Comment: Try without style attribute

Comment: Already tried ..Not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the answer to your question. But i already face the same problem before. You may use my alternative if u insist...

1 - put your Html code inside HTML file..a separate one.
2 - use below code to subtitute your code.

```
$invoiceHtml = Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_yourHtmlFile');
$pdf = new Pdf([
     // set to use core fonts only
     'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
     // A4 paper format
     'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_LANDSCAPE,
     // stream to browser inline
     'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
     // your html content input
     'content' => $invoiceHtml,
     'filename' =>$fileName,
     'cssInline' => ' @page{size: 500mm 200mm}',

      // set mPDF properties on the fly
     'options' => ['title' => 'Krajee Report Title'],
      // call mPDF methods on the fly
     'methods' => [
         'SetHeader'=>['New Horizon Travel And Tours LLC'],
     ]
]);
return $pdf->render();
```